# Get UTC offset for Timezone at given date via Ruby/tzinfo?

Tags: ruby, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset, tzinfo

This is probably trivial for anybody who knows the `tzinfo` API:

Given a `Timezone` object from `tzinfo`, how can I get the UTC offset at a given point in time (given either in local time of the Timezone or UTC)?

Comment: Isn't the offset from the UTC a property of a time in a specific time zone, and not of a date or of a time zone?

Comment: The offset should be a property of `DateTime` and `Timezone`. On Wed 09.08.2017 at 19:21 the offset of America/New_York to UTC was -4:00.

Comment: It is a property of `DateTime` **of** (or bound to) a `Timezone`, not a property of (something and) `Timezone`. Nor is it a property of "a given date".

Comment: Yes, I understand DateTime already has a Timezone stored in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`period_for_local` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/TZInfo/Timezone#period_for_local-instance_method). For these examples, I'm using the timezone I live in (`America/Sao_Paulo`), in where the offset is `-03:00` during winter (March to October) and `-02:00` during summer (Daylight Saving Time):

```
# Sao Paulo timezone
zone = TZInfo::Timezone.new('America/Sao_Paulo')

# date in January (Brazilia Summer Time - DST)
d = DateTime.new(2017, 1, 1, 10, 0)

period = zone.period_for_local(d)
puts period.offset.utc_total_offset / 3600.0

# date in July (Brazilia Standard Time - not in DST)
d = DateTime.new(2017, 7, 1, 10, 0)

period = zone.period_for_local(d)
puts period.offset.utc_total_offset / 3600.0
```

The output is:

> -2.0
>   -3.0

The `utc_total_offset` method returns the offset in seconds, so I divided by 3600 to get the value in hours.

Note that I also used `3600.0` to force the results to be a float. If I just use `3600`, the results will be rounded and timezones like `Asia/Kolkata` (which has an offset of `+05:30`) will give incorrect results (`5` instead of `5.5`).

---

Note that you must be aware of DST changes, because you can have either a gap or a overlap.

In São Paulo timezone, DST starts at October 15th 2017: at midnight, clocks shift forward to 1 AM (and offset changes from `-03:00` to `-02:00`), so all the local times between 00:00 and 01:00 are not valid. In this case, if you try to get the offset, it will get a `PeriodNotFound` error:

```
# DST starts at October 15th, clocks shift from midnight to 1 AM
d = DateTime.new(2017, 10, 15, 0, 30)
period = zone.period_for_local(d) # error: TZInfo::PeriodNotFound
```

When DST ends, at February 18th 2018, at midnight clocks shift back to 11 PM of 17th (and offset changes from `-02:00` to `-03:00`), so the local times between 11 PM and midnight exist twice (in both offsets).

In this case, you must specify which one you want (by setting the second parameter of `period_for_local`), indicating if you want the offset for DST or not:

```
# DST ends at February 18th, clocks shift from midnight to 11 PM of 17th
d = DateTime.new(2018, 2, 17, 23, 30)
period = zone.period_for_local(d, true) # get DST offset
puts period.offset.utc_total_offset / 3600.0 # -2.0

period = zone.period_for_local(d, false) # get non-DST offset
puts period.offset.utc_total_offset / 3600.0 # -3.0
```

If you don't specify the second parameter, you'll get a `TZInfo::AmbiguousTime` error:

```
# error: TZInfo::AmbiguousTime (local time exists twice due do DST overlap)
period = zone.period_for_local(d)
```

Comment: Great answer.  Also note that `period_for_utc` would be preferable if the UTC time is already known, as it wouldn't be subject to the gaps and overlaps you mentioned.

Comment: Just a small follow-up question: Is there any way to utilize the strftime("%:z") formatting?

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek One way to do it is to set the date to the offset and format it: `d.new_offset(period.offset.utc_total_offset / 3600 / 24.0).strftime('%:z')` (for me, it prints `-03:00`). Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to format the offset value directly

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response.  You just helped me solve an issue in my test suite that was caused by the recent DST switch up here in the USA.

Answer (score 1):

It seems in Ruby 1.9.3 there is some hackery (DateTime to Time) involved, with possible loss of precision, but this is my result based on the answer from @Hugo:

```
module TZInfo

class Timezone

    def utc_to_local_zone(dateTime)
        return dateTime.to_time.getlocal(self.period_for_utc(dateTime).utc_total_offset)
    end

    def offset_to_s(dateTime, format = "%z")
        return utc_to_local_zone(dateTime).strftime(format)
    end 
end

end
```